# I want to assign array of statements for every spin item selected by user

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

```
                     Intent intent = getIntent();
                        Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();

                          String freq = (String) bd.get("freq");
```

I used this code to get the value of freq.

```
                  But when i use the code below
                 if(freq == "new"),it shows invalid token.
                     {String queue[] = {"Hi","How are you"} 
                      if(freq == "old")
                            String queue[] ={"Hi","How are you","take care"}
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :`if(freq.equals("new"))`

```
But when i use the code below
                     if(freq.equals("new")),it shows invalid token.
                         {String queue[] = {"Hi","How are you"} 
                          if(freq.equals("old"))
                                String queue[] ={"Hi","How are you","take care"}
                                }
```